# How to find person in address book Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts, android-activity

I am trying to implement person lookup in Android's address book. This is how I am implementing it:

```
Cursor cur = this.context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, null, Data.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?", new String[] { mKey }, null);
if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
  Intent n = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);  
  ((Activity) this.context).startActivityForResult(n, PICK_REQUEST);
if (PICK_REQUEST != 0) {
  if (Activity.RESULT_OK != 0) {
    ((Activity) this.context).startActivity(n);
        }
    }
 } else {
    Toast.makeText(this.context, "The contact does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //  }
```

whereby `mKey` is the value of the person to search for. Nothing seems to happen when I click to search. What is it that am doing wrong?  Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: There should not be any code after `startActivityForResult`. You need to override `onActivityResult`. Either Google (or wait for someone to write the code in an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using :

```
Cursor cur = this.context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, null, Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " like '"+mKey+"%'", null, null);
```

Just check for cur.getCount()>0 to know whether you are getting related data or not.Hope,you have contact in your contact book with name mKey,else you will always get null cursor. :P

Comment: Thanks Hiral, I am still wondering about my implementation of the activity. i.e Intent n = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI); 
      ((Activity) this.context).startActivityForResult(n, PICK_REQUEST); what do you think?

Comment: Sorry.. I haven't worked onto that.Cannot help you in this!! :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, replace A1 with your Display Name

```
Cursor cursor1 = activity.getContentResolver().query(
                Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] {Contacts._ID, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, 
                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME  + "=?",
                new String[] {"A1"}, 
                null);
```

Comment: Hey Rajdeep thanks, however my cursor getcount returns 0, even though the name is actually in the contacts address book. Any thoughts?

Comment: Display name is First Name + Last Name

Comment: Thaks Rajdeep however, after testing Hiral's code, it seems to work, thanks alot though!!